# This в безымянном объекте возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, this

в js объекте без имени есть свойства. Как сделать так что бы одно свойство зависело от другого.

```
let test = {
  data: [
    {name: "3.4ска", src: this.name}, // <= Сюда смотреть надо что бы src было таким же как и name
  ],
  func: function() {
    return this.data[0];
  },
};

console.log(test.func());
```

Вот тут можно быстро проверить https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
let test = {
  data: [{
      name: "3.4ска",
      src: this.name
    }, // <= Сюда смотреть надо что бы src было таким же как и name
  ],
  func: function() {
    return this.data[0];
  },
};

console.log(test.func());
```

Comment: Я не туда глянул, вы этого не сделаете. `this` - это `window` а не `test`.

Comment: Это нормальное поведение. `this` будет указывать на экземпляр только после выполнения выражения его (экземпляра) инициализации. И только в его методах, конечно. Если надо обращаться к свойствам экземпляра на этапе его создания - используй класс с конструктором.

Comment: ...или настоящий конструктор (именованную функцию) вместо сахарного `class`ового. Это уже не суть важно, дело вкуса.